# Get html block by PHP

Tags: php, html

We have html page, it has many code inside.

Sometimes it has block `#container`, sometimes not.

All code of this page is inside `$page` variable.

How do I:

1. check, is there block with `id="container"`?
2. if html page has `#container` inside, then get it contents of this block and write to a variable `$container`.

Task should be done by php.

Comment: There are plenty of [HTML parsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) available for PHP.

Comment: @NullUserException and they are slow as hell.  Given that an id can only be used once, use a regex to check for `id="container"` then only take the performance hit of firing up the parser if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the possible ways to solve your problem is to use third party library. Let's say http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/:

```
$html->load($page);
if ($html->find('#container')) $container = $html->find('#container');
```

Answer (score -2):

Regexp is your friend here.

Good luck for your html parsing trip

Comment: Regex is a terrible solution for parsing HTML.